# Procurar o índice de um array que case com uma expressão regular

Tags: php, regex

De acordo com o Manual do PHP, a função `preg_grep` retorna as entradas de um `array` que combinam com a expressão regular.

Exemplo

```
$array = [
    'Banana',
    'Maçã',
    'Café',
    'Biscoito',
];

$array_com_B = preg_grep('/^B/i', $array);
```

Resultado:

```
['Banana', 'Biscoito']
```

Porém não existe nenhuma função com essa funcionalidade para procurar os índices de um `array` que casem com uma expressão regular.

Eu gostaria de retornar as chaves do `array` exemplificado abaixo que casem com a expressão regular `/^(id|nome)$/i`.

```
[
   'id' => 3,
   'idade' => 25,
   'nome'  => 'Wallace de Souza',
   'profissão' => 'Programador',

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você combinar as funções `array_keys`, `array_intersect_keys` e `array_flip`, vai conseguir o que quer:

```
$dados = [
    'id'        => 3,
    'idade'     => 25,
    'nome'      => 'Wallace de Souza',
    'profissão' => 'Programador',
];

$chaves = preg_grep('/^(id|nome)$/', array_keys($dados));
$dados = array_intersect_key($dados, array_flip($chaves));
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [nome] => Wallace de Souza
)
```

Comment: +1. Eu vejo muito essa chamada de `array_intersect_key` com `array_flip` nos códigos fontes do `Laravel 4`.